# Zabbix on Postgresql - very slow deletion of event

Tags: postgresql, performance, delete, postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

Were using Zabbix for monitoring and I'm having problems understanding why deleting events is so slow.

Zabbix: 4.2 (never mind the name of the db - it is 4.2)
Postgresql: 10.8
nvps: ~400
hosts: ~600
items: ~45000

event table: ~25 million rows
event_recovery table: ~12 million rows
alerts table: ~600000 rows

We've already partitioned all history* and trends* tables - which has worked fine and without problems for a year. I don't think I've seen a definitive guide on partitioning of events, and I haven't tried to figure out how to transition with partitioning of events. I would be happy for any pointers on this.

Now I've seen that housekeeping of events is very slow - a single (normally hourly) run can take more than one day to finish, so events keep stacking up. A typical slow delete statement, from the postgres log:

```
postgresql-10-20190717-031404.log:2019-07-17 03:37:43 CEST [80965]: [4-1] user=zabbix,db=zabbix_34,app=[unknown],client=[local]: LOG: duration: 27298798.930 ms statement: delete from events where (eventid between 5580621 and 5580681 or eventid between 5580689 and 5580762 or eventid between 5580769 and 5580844 or eventid between 5580851 and 5580867 or eventid between 5580869 and 5580926 or eventid between 5580933 and 5580949 or eventid between 5580963 and 5581024 
--- 8< --- a lot of similar eventids snipped away ----- 
or eventid between 5586799 and 5586839 or eventid in (5581385,5581389,5581561,5581563,5581564,5581580,5 581582,5581584,5581585,5581635))
```

I've analyzed the deletion of a single row in events. First, the contents of the three relevant tables:

```
zabbix_34=> select * from events where eventid=7123123;
 eventid | source | object | objectid |   clock    | value | acknowledged |   ns    |                 name                 | severity
---------+--------+--------+----------+------------+-------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------------+----------
 7123123 |      3 |      0 |    27562 | 1525264196 |     1 |            0 | 1980875 | Cannot calculate trigger expression. |        0
(1 row)

zabbix_34=> select * from alerts where eventid=7123123;
 alertid | actionid | eventid | userid | clock | mediatypeid | sendto | subject | message | status | retries | error | esc_step | aler
ttype | p_eventid | acknowledgeid
---------+----------+---------+--------+-------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-----
------+-----------+---------------
(0 rows)

zabbix_34=> select * from event_recovery where eventid=7123123;
 eventid | r_eventid | c_eventid | correlationid | userid
---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------
 7123123 |   7124371 |           |               |
(1 row)
```

All these queries execute in less than 1 ms, using indexes.

```
zabbix_34=> explain (analyze,timing) select * from events where eventid=7123123;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx_29337_primary on events  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=0.052..0.053 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (eventid = '7123123'::numeric)
 Planning time: 0.140 ms
 Execution time: 0.071 ms
(4 rows)

zabbix_34=> explain (analyze,timing) select * from event_recovery where eventid=7123123;
                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using event_recovery_pkey on event_recovery  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (eventid = 7123123)
 Planning time: 0.079 ms
 Execution time: 0.038 ms
(4 rows)

zabbix_34=> explain (analyze,timing) select * from alerts where eventid=7123123;
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using alerts_3 on alerts  (cost=0.42..59.81 rows=15 width=657) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (eventid = '7123123'::numeric)
 Planning time: 0.170 ms
 Execution time: 0.055 ms
(4 rows)
```

Let's delete one row:

```
zabbix_34=> explain (analyze,buffers,timing) delete from events where eventid = 7123123;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on events  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.209..0.209 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=7 dirtied=2
   ->  Index Scan using idx_29337_primary on events  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (eventid = '7123123'::numeric)
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning time: 0.071 ms
 Trigger for constraint c_alerts_5: time=259.544 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_event_suppress_1: time=0.159 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_acknowledges_2: time=0.075 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_alerts_2: time=0.104 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_event_recovery_1: time=1734.467 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_event_recovery_2: time=1869.286 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_event_recovery_3: time=770.782 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_event_tag_1: time=3.276 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_problem_1: time=1.637 calls=1
 Trigger for constraint c_problem_2: time=1.107 calls=1
 Execution time: 4640.684 ms
(17 rows)
```

5 seconds to delete a single row, wow! This shows that it is the foreign key constraints on event_recovery and alerts that take a lot of time. But why? There are indexes or primary keys (as per the schema for Zabbix 4.2) on all the referencing columns. The database is analyzed and vacuumed nightly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you upgraded your Postgresql from a version that were using "old" partitioning or you just created the zabbix database partitions on v10 partitioning?

Comment: I realise that I forgot to report on this problem. The problem was that the eventid column in the referenced table (events) and in the referencing tables (alerts and event_recovery) had different definitions, numeric in one and bigint in the other. Postgresql was not able to use the index in the referencing columns when deleting from events. After altering the column definition deletes now happen in milliseconds.

Comment: The source of this discrepancy was probably that this database was once converted from mysql to pgsql, and during this conversion data types in pgsql were chosen that did not match exactly what pgsql expects. Possibly in connection with schema updates during later upgrades? But I still haven't understood why this problem started to occur when nothing else changed in Zabbix or Pgsql....

Comment: Interesting... did you check if the query execution plan changed after changing the column definition?